# Do Jews have an obligation to support the effort to free Jonathan Pollard?

Tags: halacha, money, current-events, pidyon-shvuyim-prisoners

I am not entirely clear on all of the particulars of the mitzvah of pidyon shivuyim - redeeming Jewish captives. Nor am I positive that someone jailed by a democratic goverment for breaking secular law would be included in the parameters of pidyon shivuyim. However, I have seen many different organizations with Rabbinic support that claim it is incumbent on every Jew to support the efforts to free [Jonathan Pollard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Pollard). I do not know what the halachic basis is for these claims, if any. Nor am I sure if this would fall under a more *hazy* category of "All Jews are responsible, one for another" or any other Jewish parameter which enjoins one Jew to help another. Therefore I ask:

Does a Jew have an obligation to support, financially or in any other way, efforts to free [Jonathan Pollard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Pollard)?

Answer (score 4):

[Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu Z"L](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6045) said, in 2007, that it is the true Mitzva of Pidyon Shevuyim to help Jonathan Pollard. This is due to the fact that he endangered himself in order to help the Jewish nation.

Comment: Could you flesh this out more? What Halachic sources or reasoning does R' Eliyahu use to determine that this Mitzva applies in this case?

Comment: @IsaacMoses: How can I tell you what sources R'Eliyahu used when the article does not indicate what they are?

Comment: I haven't read the article. Without sources or reasoning, this is a pretty weak answer. The only thing it has going for it is the authority of R' Eliyahu, which is significant, but only helps us as far as knowing his conclusion on this case, in particular, which, by itself, is not very interesting.

Comment: How does R' Eliyahu know that what he did was in the interests of the Jewish nation and not in his own interests or in delusional fantasy about what was in someone's interests? And by Jewish nation does he mean Jews worldwide or Israel?

Comment: ... It is also not even obvious from this answer whether this was, in fact, a Halachic pesak by R' Eliyahu or whether it was an off-the-cuff answer to an interview question or a political speech, either of which would carry much less weight, even given his authority.

Comment: @SethJ: As I am not R'Eliyahu I do not know how and what he knows. I do believe that if he feels that what Jonathan Pollard did was in the interest of the Jewish nation - it is proper to trust him - as in Emunas Chachomim.

Comment: All: Please reread this answer before posting a comment. If your comment helps to clarify the answer, or seeks improvement of it from its poster, go right ahead: that's what comments are for. Otherwise, take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468). (I have deleted a bunch of comments.)

Comment: @GershonGold There is no way that is a proper application of Emunas Chachomim.

Comment: But since spying on Israel's biggest ally could cause negative repercussions for Israel then the spy could also be seen to be a *rodef* on the *tzibbur*?